# **Android Web view not taking enter as input **

Tags: android, webview

I am not able to use enter in my webview android keyboard. After I use enter the text goes out of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with android webview. See the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6965). I needed to show a new line in my webview and because it didnot support "\r\n" and "\n" I needed to use "
" tag.

Comment: I am writing as    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://apj,index.php", readFileAsString("index.html"),"text/html", "utf-8", "");   What should be the second argument for loadDataWithBaseURL(.....),the base uri is the webpage where i want conversion.